# Can't take a screenshot on instagram.com with Phantomjs code example, why it's always a black screen?

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is mine phantomjs super easy code(test2.js):

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://instagram.com', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

cmd code:

```
phantomjs.exe --ignore-ssl-errors=true  test2.js
```

results - always a black screenshot, blank

Comment: It might be capturing the screenshot before its being loaded fully, put a condition to check whether the elements are loaded or not then call the render.

Comment: Also: you should use a real useragent, set the viewport to some of a real screen size (default is 400x300), and probably use `page.onError` callback to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that page is not processed yet when you are taking the screenshot. You should wait for page to fully load (with javascript processing). You can simply check that out by changing this line:

```
page.render('example.png');
```

to something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   page.render('example.png');
   phantom.exit();
},15000);
```

Please note, that it's not a good idea to wait given amount of time... it's better to use some `WaitFor` function...

For example:

```
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 5000, //< Default Max Timout is 5s
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx()); //< defensive code
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("  * Timeout, exiting.");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady(); //< Do what it's supposed to do once the condition is fulfilled
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};
```

Example usage:

```
waitFor(function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        return ((document.documentElement.textContent || document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('© 2018 INSTAGRAM') > -1); // <-- this may be some other string or other condition - don't know instagram site at all... generally it should return true if the element was found and false if not.
    });
    },function(){       
        page.render('example.png');
    }
);
```